# unable to access Socket class in java in client and server for arp

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on a client and server program for arp in java which uses Socket. When I compile it I get error like this the code looks like this. Stack Overflow is asking me more details about my code but I don't have more details about this code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.Socket.*;
class arpserver
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket(2500);
            System.out.println("Server started");
            Socket client = null;
            client = soc.accept();
            String str;
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec("ifconfig eth0");
            BufferedReader pin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String haddr = "";
            String ipaddr = br.readLine();
            int flag = 0;
            while((str = pin.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(str);
                if((str.indexOf("HWaddr")) != -1)
                {
                    int tlen = str.length();
                    int hlen = tlen - 19;
                    haddr = str.substring(hlen,tlen);
                }
                else if ((str.indexOf(ipaddr)) != -1)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 1)
                ps.println(haddr);
            ps.close();
            br.close();
            pin.close();
            client.close();
            soc.close();
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + io.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

During compilation I get this error

```
S:\>javac arpserver.java
arpserver.java:12: cannot access Socket
bad class file: .\Socket.java
file does not contain class Socket
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpa
th.
Socket client = null;
^
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a local `Socket.java` file and that this file does not compile. This custom `Socket` class is located in the same package (root?) as your `arpserver` class, so it is chosen before the `java.net.Socket` class which you are trying to access.

As a stand-alone class, your `arpserver` class should compile - at least, a raw "copy-paste" compiled fine for me.

Comment: In your `S:\ ` directory, is there a `Socket.java` file there? At least that's what it looks like to me from the error message.

Comment: Does it change anything if you try to "fully qualify" your reference to the Socket class? I.e. on line 12, change Socket to `java.net.Socket`?